# How do I split an integer into 2 byte binary in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Have ready C# code to split integer into 2 bytes as you can see below, Needs to re-write same in Ruby-

```
int seat2 = 65000;
```

// Split into two bytes

```
    byte seats = (byte)(seat2 & 0xFF); // lower byte
    byte options = (byte)((seat2 >> 8) & 0xFF); // upper byte
```

Below is the output above

Output Seats => 232
options => 253

// Merge back into integer

```
        seat2 = (options << 8) | seats;
```

Please suggest anyone has any solution to rewrite the above in Ruby

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Also, you could simply try `seat2 = 65000`, `seat2 & 0xFF` and `(seat2 >> 8) & 0xFF` in a Ruby console. You'll be amazed!

Comment: Shortest option: `upper, lower = 65000.divmod(256)`

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk: Nice!

Comment: @EricDuminil  We have licensing algorithm in place and has two parameter seats & options each variable carrying single byte , we have to increase seats capacity without making change in his byte, then we decided to use seats & options to store 65000 number we divide number into 2 bytes and later merge it back while obtaining that number. It completed successfully based on the answer posted by people. thanks to all as you saved my time.

Answer (score 4):

The code you wrote would work well in Ruby with very few modifications.

You could simply try:

```
seat2 = 65000
seat2 & 0xFF
# => 232
(seat2 >> 8) & 0xFF
# => 253
```

An alternative would be to use `pack` and `unpack`:

```
[65000].pack('S').unpack('CC')
# => [232, 253]
[232, 253].pack('CC').unpack('S')
# => [65000]
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, this exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Another one:

```
lower, upper = 65000.digits(256)
```

Comment: mind that you can get nil for values < 256 :  0.digits(256) #[nil,0]

Answer (score 2):

I believe the most idiomatic way for binary transformations in Ruby is [`Array#pack`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [`String#unpack`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/String.html#method-i-unpack) (like in [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54944630/8098012)).

Also you have an option to use [Numeric#divmod](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) with 256(2^8, byte size):

```
> upper, lower = 65000.divmod(256)
# => [253, 232]
> upper
# => 253
> lower
# => 232
```

In this case, to have correct bytes, your Integer should not exceed 65535 (2^16-1).